# JellyBean Newcastle ANDROID 4.1.1 screen size issue after device is unlocked

Tags: android-intent, android-4.2-jelly-bean, screen-size

I have observed that when activity gets changed when device is locked, activity's bottom part gets cut on unlocking the device.

For e.g. Set sleep time of device as 15 sec and write a code which changes activity after 20 sec of phone's idle time. Now if I keep phone idle for 21 sec and unlock the phone, changed activity gets cut. I have observed that Soft Menu displays over the activity which eats my activity's bottom part. I have put logs and analyzed that after unlocking I am getting height of window as 1845 while in normal case it is 1701.

The code I am using to get size of window is ::

```
int initialWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int initialHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int statusBarHeight = getDefaultStatusBarHeight(displayMetrics.densityDpi);
Rect screenSize= new Rect();
screenSize.right = initialWidth;
screenSize.bottom = initialHeight - statusBarHeight; //screenSize is what we are using           //to display screen.

//code we are using to get status bar heigth.
private int getDefaultStatusBarHeight(int densityDpi) {
    int statusBarHeight = 0;
    switch (densityDpi) {
    case 120:
        statusBarHeight = 19;
        break;

    case 160:
        statusBarHeight = 25;
        break;

    case 240:
        statusBarHeight = 38;
        break;

    default:
        statusBarHeight = Math.round((float) densityDpi * 25 / 160);
    }
    return statusBarHeight;
}
```

I am facing this issue in Newcastle ANDROID 4.1.1 having soft menu bar like ICS device.

Has anybody faced the same issue? If yes then whats the solution?